# is that possible to add controls into WebUserControl from aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, custom-controls, webusercontrol

for example the user control i created is a dock panel, and i want to make it to allow add others controls from aspx page.

```
<uc1:dockPanel ID="dockPanel1" runat="server" >
  --add control to here from aspx page--
</uc1:dockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my research i found something like this.. so we can add an inner property inside the WebUserControl, for example.. but the problem that i facing now is the control is not render inside WebUserControl, its render in the page.

HTML

```
 <uc1:dockPanel ID="dockPanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="ASPxButton">
                </dx:ASPxButton>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </uc1:dockPanel>
```

ASCX
 [ParseChildren(true)]

```
public partial class dockPanel :System.Web.UI.UserControl, INamingContainer
{

    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    [TemplateContainer(typeof(dockPanel))]
    public ITemplate ContentTemplate { get; set; }

     protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            if (ContentTemplate != null)
                ContentTemplate.InstantiateIn(this);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You load controls dynamically via control.add method. First get an object of user control and then use control.add property for that.

See following link for the reference.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287574(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i know this way but this is not the thing that i needed.. i want to dynamically add control from aspx page into the WebUserControl.

Comment: Hi I have written a blog post about it. http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2013/08/dynetnamically-add-control-to-aspnet-user-control.html

Comment: solved.. jalpesh thanks for your help.. if needed can refer to this =))http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/2/asp.net/how-to-create-an-asp.net-control-that-behaves-as-a-template-container-to-nest-content-via-markup